# Lightning ToolingAPI BETA Documentation

Tags: apex, tooling-api, lightning-aura-components, aura

Thanks to @DougChasman we have learned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57444/aura-lightning-access-via-toolingapi-or-metadataapi) that both ToolingAPI and MetadataAPI are fully supporting AuraDefinitionBundel and AuraDefinition right now as BETA and we can start to use them.

Doug also provided links to the [MetadataAPI documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#CSHID=meta_auradefinitionbundle.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fmeta_auradefinitionbundle.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp), which helped me a lot to  implement it into [CodeFusion](http://www.elastify.eu/apps/CodeFusion) using MetadataAPI.

Now I would be very interested, if there is also a bit of documentation about Aura regarding ToolingAPI. As with other Metadata-Types, I'd like to support both APIs switchable, wherever possible.

Or has anyone already saved an AuraDefinition as single File via ToolingAPI? I would prefer not to deploy the entire Bundle but only save e. g. MyAppController.js - is that possible?

Probably I could answer most of my questions to myself by looking at Dave's https://github.com/heroku/force - but if anyone already used ToolingAPI for Aura deployment, any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: In your question, you mention "AuraDefinitionBundle" and "AuraDefinition". What is an "AuraDefinition"? I've only ever seen [**AuraDefinitionBundle**](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_auradefinitionbundle.htm).

Comment: Never mind. I see it listed as a Tooling API object type in [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have finally added Tooling API doc for:
 o AuraDefinition (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/sforce_api_objects_auradefinition.htm)
 o AuraDefinitionBundle (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/sforce_api_objects_auradefinitionbundle.htm)

Apologies that it took a while for the doc to appear.

Answer (score 4):

Uwe, yes, it is possible to save a single `AuraDefinition` object via the Tooling API, right now in **Winter '15** (API 32.0). I confirmed this using [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com).

Your endpoint for updating the `AuraDefinition` record in Salesforce is shown in the [Tooling API documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/intro_rest_overview.htm) as `/sobjects/`*`SObjectName`*`/`*`id`*`/`. Below is a sample full endpoint for updating an `AuraDefinition` record in my DE org.

https://ccmt-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/tooling/sobjects/AuraDefinition/0Adj0000000CcolCAC/

To save new code for a particular definition (e.g., Helper), all you need to do is send an **HTTP PATCH** request to an `AuraDefinition` record's endpoint, with the JSON payload including a "Source" value. See the sample request payload below for a new Helper definition.

```
{
    "Source":"({\n    /* Helper functions go here */\n})"
}
```